# Cant sign in to pokemon go through google or pokemon trainer club on my new phone

Tags: pokemon-go

When i put my date of birth and try to sign in to my pokemon go account on my new phone  through google it says unable to authenticate access. Please try again later. I even tried going through the pokemon trainer club but i keprtgetting the same thing!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that Niantic identified and tried to fix in patch 0.55 for android. It should be fixed now. If it is not, please contact their support.